# Optimize pattern of rotating holes for all combinations

Tags: optimization, geometry

Sort of a programming question, sort of a general logic question. Imagine a circular base with a pattern of circles:

[image]

And another circle, mounted above and able to rotate, with holes that expose the colored circles below:

[image]

There must be an optimal pattern of either the colored circles or the openings (or both) that will allow for all N possible combinations of colors... but I have no idea how to attack the problem! At this point, combinations of 2 seem probably the easiest and would be fine as a starting point (red/blue, red/green, red/white, etc).

I would imagine there will need to be gaps in the colors, unlike the example above. Any suggestions welcome!

Edit: clarified the question (hopefully!) thanks to feedback from [Robert Harvey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102937/robert-harvey)

Comment: Your question is under-specified.  For example, as your question is currently asked, I can get all combinations of colors by simply drilling a hole in the top plate in all color positions.

Comment: Perhaps not fully explained - I want all possible combinations of N (say 2, meaning red/blue, blue/green, green/red, etc).

Comment: That's a combinations/permutations problem.

Comment: Yep, but with an ordering twist; duplicates would be ok. Perhaps this is a lot more straight-forward than I am thinking - any help in the right direction would be great.

Comment: http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html

Comment: Well, helpful for the basics of permutations/combinations (which I understand already) but not much else.

This has to do with physically ordering in an optimal way. Might the spacing of the holes - perhaps not right next to each other - help facilitate the combinations? How many duplicates would be required? Would combinations of 2 be better acheived with 3 holes and some gaps? 

I think this is a lot more complex than you're giving it credit for. If we could reopen the question for more than a few minutes, perhaps some other folks would like to try to help.

Comment: As already stated, your question is under-specified.  Even though it has been reopened, it remains unclear.  What are the exact rules of this system?  Does partial coverage count?  Can your holes be much smaller than the dots?  Can you have multiple plates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two holes, you could look for a perfect matching in a bipartite graph, each permutation described by two nodes, one in each partition. Nodes would be connected if they share one element, i.e. the `(blue,red)` node from the first partition connected to the `(red,green)` node of the second. The circles arranged in the same distance would allow for both of these patterns. A perfect matching in that graph would correspond to chains or cycles of permutations where two of them always share a single color. A bit like dominoes. If you had a set of cycles of the same length, you could interleave them to form the pattern on the lower disk. I'm not sure how easy it will be to obtain these same length cycles, though, and I also don't know how to generalize this to more than two elements in each permutation.